# Css toogle button passing two different argument alternately with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to pass ('A', 'B') with the first click on the toggle button and ('A', 'C') in the second one.

Do I need to a third argument, a boolean one, to control the toggle state and use the conditional rendering with 2 toggle buttons?

```
                <div class="filter">
                    <div class="filter-inner toggle" v-on:click="search( 'A', 'B')">
                        <label class="switch ">
                        <input type="checkbox ">
                        <span class="slider round "></span>
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-on:` accepts any JavaScript expression, you can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
console.clear();

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstSearch: true
  },
  methods: {
    search(arg1, arg2) {
      this.firstSearch = false;
      console.log(arg1, arg2);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="firstSearch ? search('A', 'B') : search('A', 'C')">Click me</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

But a better solution would be to outsource the logic to the method itself (or create another one that calls `search`).